# I got a small issue when i transform: scale my menu items

Tags: html, css

I have a menu like so:

```
<div class="menu">
  <div class="menu__item">
    <ul class="menu__item__link">
      <li>menu 1</li>
      <li>menu 2</li>
    </ul>
     <ul class="menu__item__links">
      <li>sub menu 1</li>
      <li>sub menu 2</li>
      <li>sub menu 3</li>
      <li>sub menu 4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
   <div class="menu__item">
    <ul class="menu__item__link">
      <li>menu 1</li>
      <li>menu 2</li>
    </ul>
     <ul class="menu__item__links">
      <li>sub menu 1</li>
      <li>sub menu 2</li>
      <li>sub menu 3</li>
      <li>sub menu 4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
   <div class="menu__item">
    <ul class="menu__item__link">
      <li>menu 1</li>
      <li>menu 2</li>
    </ul>
     <ul class="menu__item__links">
      <li>sub menu 1</li>
      <li>sub menu 2</li>
      <li>sub menu 3</li>
      <li>sub menu 4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<h2>Some text here</h2>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/takebyfy/

when i transform: scale my menu items the **h2** a the bottom is moving to the right. I have some another pages with this menu and i dont want to move elements at the bottom of menu. When menu scaling it must hover elements at the bottom.

Comment: If you can know the height for the items menu you can use that value to fix the height and prevent moving the h2 https://jsfiddle.net/takebyfy/2/

Comment: Good answer. Post it like an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First at all for good practice clear your floats with:

```
.menu:after {
  content:"";
  display:table;
  clear:both;
}
```

Then for your issue you can have two options:

**Fixed Height ::**

If you can know the size of the menu_item you can set it as the max-height preventing the offset of the content:

```css
body {
  background:#ccc;
}
.menu:after {
  content:"";
  display:table;
  clear:both;
}
.menu__item {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5px;
  height:70px;
}
.menu__item:hover {
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
.menu__item:hover .menu__item__links {
  display: block;
  background:white;
}
.menu__item__link {
   list-style-type: none;
}
.menu__item__links {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div class="menu__item">
    <ul class="menu__item__link">
      <li>menu 1</li>
      <li>menu 2</li>
    </ul>
     <ul class="menu__item__links">
      <li>sub menu 1</li>
      <li>sub menu 2</li>
      <li>sub menu 3</li>
      <li>sub menu 4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
   <div class="menu__item">
    <ul class="menu__item__link">
      <li>menu 1</li>
      <li>menu 2</li>
    </ul>
     <ul class="menu__item__links">
      <li>sub menu 1</li>
      <li>sub menu 2</li>
      <li>sub menu 3</li>
      <li>sub menu 4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
   <div class="menu__item">
    <ul class="menu__item__link">
      <li>menu 1</li>
      <li>menu 2</li>
    </ul>
     <ul class="menu__item__links">
      <li>sub menu 1</li>
      <li>sub menu 2</li>
      <li>sub menu 3</li>
      <li>sub menu 4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<h2>Some text here</h2>
```

---

**Absolute Position**

To prevent the increase size of the menu item an therefore the offset of the content below, use absolute position for the subitem menu:

```css
body {
  background:#ccc;
}
.menu:after {
  content:"";
  display:table;
  clear:both;
}
.menu__item {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5px;
  position:relative;
}
.menu__item:hover {
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
.menu__item:hover .menu__item__links {
  display: block;
  background:white;
}
.menu__item__link {
   list-style-type: none;
}
.menu__item__links {
  display: none;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  top:100%;
  background:white;
  padding:0 20px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div class="menu__item">
    <ul class="menu__item__link">
      <li>menu 1</li>
      <li>menu 2</li>
    </ul>
     <ul class="menu__item__links">
      <li>sub menu 1</li>
      <li>sub menu 2</li>
      <li>sub menu 3</li>
      <li>sub menu 4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
   <div class="menu__item">
    <ul class="menu__item__link">
      <li>menu 1</li>
      <li>menu 2</li>
    </ul>
     <ul class="menu__item__links">
      <li>sub menu 1</li>
      <li>sub menu 2</li>
      <li>sub menu 3</li>
      <li>sub menu 4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
   <div class="menu__item">
    <ul class="menu__item__link">
      <li>menu 1</li>
      <li>menu 2</li>
    </ul>
     <ul class="menu__item__links">
      <li>sub menu 1</li>
      <li>sub menu 2</li>
      <li>sub menu 3</li>
      <li>sub menu 4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<h2>Some text here</h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the way you have this coded with HTML. It's a bit unconventional for what you are looking to do.

You need to set position relative / absolute for the target elements. See below, it's not perfect but will lead you in the right direction to improve.

`.menu__item {
      background-color: #fff;
      width: 30%;
      float: left;
      margin-left: 5px;
      position: relative;
    }
    .menu__item:hover {
      transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
      transform: scale(1.2);
    }
    .menu__item:hover .menu__item__links {
      display: block;
    }
    .menu__item__link {
       list-style-type: none;
    }
    .menu__item__links {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      background: #fff;
      width: auto;
    }`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set elements on a page, you need to add "position" on the elements. Once you have that, set the z-index on them ( it goes from highest to lowest in terms of what you want to see ). For this example, I just add this CSS to make this happen.

```
 h2 { position: absolute; left: 10px; top: 60px; z-index: 0;} 
 .menu { position: relative; z-index: 10; }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/takebyfy/1/

Comment: My elements in the bottom wont have position: absolute ;(

Comment: Its just an example, switch out position: absolute; with relative, the important thing is the z-index

Comment: Then it's not working, but the z-index not prevent moving the h2 element to the right side

Comment: why don't you add the rest of your page and let me take a look

Comment: I think `position: absolute;` i will use for menu__item__links and it will prevent moving the bottom elements.